# How to create smart mailbox to show redirected mail?

Tags: mail.app

The only way I have found to find a redirected email item is to look for the little -> icon on the left of each message so redirected.  Is there a way to set a rule looking for that in a smart mailbox?  And if not, has anyone requested that feature?  Thanks.  Boyd

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Smart Mailbox criteria doesn't include a way to search all email headers, because only a portion of them is actually indexed in the Spotlight database. However, you can make a workaround by combining mail rules and existing smart mailbox criteria. The goal is to use one of the indexed criteria such as a flag colour you don't use anywhere else and have mail rule evaluation set that flag on messages that are resent.

Create a new email rule in **Mail/Preferences/Rules/Add Rule**. Open the conditions popup and you will see many more compared to Smart Mailbox. However, *Resent-From* is not there, but we can fix that by choosing *Edit header list...*, adding a *Resent-From* and selecting it.

[image: Edit header list]

Type your email address as I assume you are interested in email messages that *you* redirected, right? As the action taken simply flag your message what a colour you selected.

[image: Mail rules]

The final step is creating a smart mailbox using the flag as the search criteria.

[image: smart mailbox]

The end effect is that whenever you redirect an email message, the flag gets applied automatically and it shows up in the smart mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think boris42's answer is better than mine because it is strictly looking for the "Resent-From" header.

I'm lazy so my solution is to use the "Any recipient" header for the smart mailbox.

> Any recipient **is equal to** *Mailboxredirectingemails@emailaddress.com*